# I am running Register, Homepage and CreateNewProject with the help of xml file in the TestNG, but only Register is getting executed

Tags: testng, pom.xml, browser-automation, testng-eclipse

I have tried grouping, setup etc. (Tests are provided with the proper annotations)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="project.Register"/>

      <class name="project.HomePage"/>
    <class name="project.CreateNewProject"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Can you show class CreateNewProject tests?

Comment: plz provide exceptions faced, how you initialized webdriver and classes implementation to help you